# Cplex C++ interface. How to clean up memory?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, cplex

**Background:** The C++ interface of IBM ILOG Cplex allocates and de-allocates memory rather unconventionally:

A declaration of an ILO environment `IloEnv environment;`, followed by a construction of models and solvers within this environment, followed by all these objects (including the environment) going out of scope results in a memory leak. Note that I have not used the `new` operator. One way to avoid this is to call `environment.end();` before the object goes out of scope.

**Setting:** Now, I have a class whose purpose is to solve a specific ILP. This class has some member variables:

```
IloEnv ilpEnvironment_;
IloObjective ilpObjective_;
IloExpr ilpExpression_;
IloModel ilpModel_;
IloCplex ilpSolver_;
IloNumArray ilpSolution_;
IloNumVarArray ilpVariables_;
IloNumArray ilpStartValues_;
IloRangeArray constraints_;
```

These member variables are initialized in the initializer list of the constructor:

```
inline MyClass::MyClass() 
:   ilpEnvironment_(),
    ilpObjective_(ilpEnvironment_),
    ilpExpression_(ilpEnvironment_),
    ilpModel_(ilpEnvironment_),
    ilpSolver_(ilpModel_),
    ilpSolution_(ilpEnvironment_),
    ilpVariables_(ilpEnvironment_),
    ilpStartValues_(ilpEnvironment_),
    constraints_(ilpEnvironment_)
{ /* ... */ }
```

The destructor de-allocates all the memory (that has been allocated by member functions of the class that operate on the member variables):

```
inline MyClass::~MyClass() {
    ilpEnvironment_.end();
}
```

**Question:** How do i implement a member function `void clear()` that de-allocates the memory and puts the class back into its initial state? Here are two rather naive attempts I made that don't work:

```
inline void MyClass::clear() {
    ilpEnvironment_.end();
    ilpEnvironment_ = IloEnv(); // does not work, whether or not I comment this line out
    ilpObjective_ = IloObjective(ilpEnvironment_);
    ilpExpression_ = IloExpr(ilpEnvironment_);
    ilpModel_ = IloModel(ilpEnvironment_);
    ilpSolver_ = IloCplex(ilpEnvironment_);
    ilpSolution_ = IloNumArray(ilpEnvironment_);
    ilpVariables_ = IloNumVarArray(ilpEnvironment_);
    ilpStartValues_ = IloNumArray(ilpEnvironment_);
    constraints_ = IloRangeArray(ilpEnvironment_);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose of the class is to solve a specific ILP model, then I would initialize the class with the model size/parameters, and create and destroy the CPLEX objects within a solve() member function while saving only the results as class members.  Class members would be model parameters, and the object would keep all CPLEX dealings hidden.

You could even have a class member that keeps track of which constraints to activate in that particular solve() call.

If you absolutely *have* to use the CPLEX objects as changeable class members, then you might want to try to use object pointers as class members instead of the objects themselves.  Calling IloEnv::end() destroys the objects associated with it, so you could call IloEnd::end() and then reassign the pointers to new objects.